# Безопасный update базы через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Вношу изменения в базе через ajax(post method) на php файл. На данный момент как я понимаю каждый может прислать post запрос на мой php файл и изменить значение в базе. Есть какие-либо варианты сделать работу по обновлению базы через ajax безопасной?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под безопасной работой?

Comment: Ну, по идее авторизацию просто сделать и в php-скрипте проверять, Вы это или кто-то другой его запустил.

Comment: Думаю тут хватит проверки - откуда делается запрос, если запрос происходит со стороннего ресурса - блокировать, а иначе вопрос поставлен не корректно и должна быть как уже пометили, авторизация. Под защитой можно подразумевать тот-же `defined('SEC') || exit;`.

Answer (score 0):

Если в скрипте нет авторизации, то полностью защитить метод не получится.
Есть ряд приемов, каждый нацелен на определенный вид атаки.
Самое простое - запретить выполнение скрипта через прямой запрос в браузере. Для этого нужно проверить заголовок HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH.
Далее можно добавить csrf токены в запрос. Сами токены хранить в сессии. Приватная и публичная часть токена хранится в сессии, на странице, с которой осуществляется ajax запрос  - только публичная. При обработке запроса две части надо сравнить. Это позволит защитить скрипт от выполнения ботами, которые все-таки смогли авторизоваться в системе.